# How to call a fragment from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-gridview

Gridview created in Activty. Gridview Clickevent call the fragment, but Fragment is not called.  Android Studio is not giving any error.

I have created Home fragment.

Activity is not call to Home Fragment and not given any error.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
gridViewGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position){

            case 0 :

               Fragment fragment = new Home();
               FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment); // fragment container id in first parameter is the  container(Main layout id) of Activity
               transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // this will manage backstack
               transaction.commit();

            break;
}}}
```

Comment: You don't "call" Fragments. Fragments are contained in Activities. You can add/remove  them or replace them with other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FragmentManager instead:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
Class FragmentClass = Home.class;
try {
    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack(null) // your manage backstack here
    .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
    .commit();
```

Take note it's import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: home fragment is not open

Comment: @raj what do you mean by not open? How do you implement Home fragment? Can edit in your post?